# Attempting to call my function n times

Tags: r

My goal is to call my dice roll function n times where n is the amount of turns. This is a monopoly simulated turn and as such the doubles will roll again, and triples will go to jail. I cannot figure out how to set this up so my function will be

```
Diceroll <- Function ( Turns, Sides) 

Diceroll <- function(Turn,sides){


      Turn = as.integer(0)
      First_roll = as.integer(0)
      Second_roll = as.integer(0)
      Third_roll = as.integer(0)
      Fourth_roll = as.integer(0)
      Fifth_roll = as.integer(0)
      Sixth_roll = as.integer(0)
      Total = as.integer(0)
      i = as.integer(1)

      for (i in 1:Turn) { 


      First_roll = sample(1:sides,size = 1)
      Second_roll = sample(1:sides,size = 1)

      if(First_roll[1] == Second_roll[1]) {
        Third_roll = sample(1:sides,size = 1)
        Fourth_roll = sample(1:sides,size = 1)

      } 

      if(Third_roll[1] == Fourth_roll[1] & Third_roll[1] + Fourth_roll[1] > 0) {
        Fifth_roll= sample(1:sides,size = 1)
        Sixth_roll = sample(1:sides,size = 1)

      }

      if(Fifth_roll[1] == Sixth_roll[1] & Fifth_roll[1] + Sixth_roll[1] > 0)   { Total = "Jail"

      }

      else {

            Total = (First_roll[1] + Second_roll[1] + Third_roll[1] + 
                       Fourth_roll[1] + Fifth_roll[1] + Sixth_roll[1]) }




       return(Total)

      }

      }
```

Here is my attempt but it is only listed the value of one roll.

Comment: Thar first line is a stray. Also, why do you have a parameter, `Turn`, which you ignore by setting equal to 0?

Comment: I wanted to set that just as a placeholder and then use a for loop specifying the new value. I am not sure what you mean by first line is a stray.

Comment: `Diceroll <- Function ( Turns, Sides)` looks like a typo that your forgot to edit out.

Comment: By setting `Turn` variable to 0 at the beginning of your function, you're effectively ignoring the user's input. There's no need for a placeholder for `Turn` since it is directly fed into your for loop when the function is called. What you might want to do is set a default for `Turn`.

Comment: Question: if you are rolling n times you have an output of n rolls. However, you say that if you roll doubles you roll again. Does that mean that you roll n times + the number of times doubles are rolled? Or am I missunderstanding the goal of the output?

Comment: The question is quite unclear and what you have is overly complicated. For example, for a single roll just use `roll <- sample(1:6, 2, replace = TRUE)` instead of separate variables for each die. It also isn't clear that it makes sense to have the rolling function be responsible for checking if there is a double and rerolling (or going to jail) if it is. That should be part of the function that simulates a turn. Having single functions do too much is a blueprint for convoluted, hard to debug, code.

Comment: I agree. I am new and my function was too long. Here is my new code 

Test2 <- function(n,d) {
  
  x = replicate(n, sample(1:d, 2, replace = TRUE))
  
  y = Reduce("+",x)
  
  
  return(y)
}



I am wondering now how to add to/ create a new function that basically says if the sample(1:d, 2, replace = TRUE) are equal to eachother then roll again. 

Put simply I need to create doubles function to "roll again" This be continuous with n


Edit: Not sure how to make my code appear in the desired format. CRTL + K not working. refers me to "Search Google"